# How to write a router.navigate method to navigate to parent module from child module in angular6

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I am able to navigate from parent module to child module , in the same way i want to navigate back to the parent module from child module. by using only typescript router.navigate method.

From html view able to navigate but its not working for typescript file.

for example like

> `this.router.navigate['../../',value1];`

Answer (score 0):

you can add in your routing module and object call data and pass the route you need for example

```
path: 'users',
    loadChildren: 'some/route/here/here.module#HereModule',
    data: { title: 'title view', urlParent: 'parentRoute' },
```

after you use in your child component with activatedRoute from @angular/router something like this (do not forget injection dependency of activatedRoute in your constructor)

```
this.urlParent = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data.urlParent;
```

with that you can use your `` this.router.navigate[`${this.urlParent}`] ``

Comment: Thanks ferreira, I solved this in a simple way that which is angular library itself proving it  this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.route.parent });